# Integral of Square of Mean Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

(1)If $T^{2}$ represents standardized torus and $H$ is its mean curvature, then wen have $\int_{T^{2}}H^{2}dV\geq2\pi^{2}$.
(2)If $\Sigma$ represents a compact surface whose $g=1$ in $E^{3}$ and $H$ is its mean curvature, then we have $\int_{\Sigma}H^{2}dV\geq2\pi^{2}$.
(3)I want to ask can these theorems be generalized to a compact surface whose $g=0$ and $g>1$ in $E^3$ or how to be generalized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how (1) and (2) are different. I don't know anything about this but here is what it seems:

This is known as the [Willmore conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willmore_conjecture) and was shown in 2012 by Marques and Neves. They also showed that the same bound holds for higher genus, and equality only holds for some round torus.

Also, it is possible to show with elementary means that any closed immersed surface (including genus $0$) has its "Willmore energy" (the integral you wrote) bounded below by $4\pi$, and that equality holds only for round spheres.

I suggest you take a look at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92013/willmore-minimizers-for-genus-geq-2) and [this](http://matheuscmss.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/the-willmore-conjecture-after-fernando-coda-marques-and-andre-neves/).